# scala convert Array[Product] to Array[MyType]

Tags: arrays, scala, type-conversion

I have my own class:

```
case class QueueObject[K, V](priority: K, e: V)(implicit prior: K => Ordered[K]) {
  require(e != null, "Can't put null element in queue. Please put another type of data!")
  type PQObject = QueueObject[K, V]

  def eq(other: PQObject): Int = if (priority >= other.priority) 1 else -1
}
```

In other class I have

```
case class QueueClass[K, V](container: Array[QueueObject[K, V]]) {
...
type PQObject = QueueObject[K, V]
type PQContainer = Array[PQObject]
val array: PQContainer = container
...
```

So I try to update my array like this:

```
def deleteElement(array: PQContainer):PQContainer = array.updated(0, array.lastOption).init
```

But result of this func is ***Array[Product with Serializable]***, so I need ***Array[PQObject]***. 
How can I convert result type to my own? (I'm new in Scala, so, pls don't flame)

Comment: The `K => Ordered[K]` should probably be an `Ordering[K]`, and it should be attached to `QueueClass`, not to `QueueObject`. It does not make any sense if every object in the queue has its own idea about how to compare priorities.

Comment: How will it look like?
 **case class QueueObject[K : Ordering[K], V](priority: K, e: V)** like this?

Comment: Rather `K: Ordering` (without `[K]`). But it would be essentially just syntactic sugar for what you have now (every `QueueObject` would have its own `Ordering`). I'd rather declare `QueueClass[K: Ordering, V]`, and then add the ordering as an implicit parameter in the methods of `QueueObject` that actually need it. Actually, I'd probably try to make `QueueObject` an inner class inside `QueueClass`. Furthermore, I wouldn't override `eq`, because `eq` is the method that checks referential equality, and should return `Boolean`.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin sry, but I have problem again. If I do like this: **case class QueueObject[K: Ordering, V](priority: K, e: V) {** I can't use **>=** in my new equals **override def equals(obj: PQObject): Boolean = if (this.priority >= obj.priority) true else false**

Comment: IIRC, something like `val ord = implicitly[Ordering[K]]; import ord._` should do the trick. But then you can pass `implicit ord: Ordering[K]` directly. Switching to `K: Ordering` instead of `implicit ord: Ordering[K]` was not my point. My point was that it doesn't make any sense if every entry `(K, V)` has its own ordering. By the way: your `equals` is not even symmetric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to replace the first element with `lastOption`.

The type of `lastOption` is `Option[PQObject]` and the scala compiler inferes the common supertype of `PQObject` and `Option[PQObject]` to be `Product with Serializable` -- which is a very generic (useless) type.

Try this:

```
array.lastOption.foreach(array.update(0, _))
array.init
```

*edit*:

Since, `init` throws an exception when the array is empty, you may as well just use `last` instead of `lastOption`.

Comment: Oh, Thanks a lot!)

Comment: is this check relevant in Scala for init

     _**def deleteElement(array: PQContainer): PQContainer = if (array.nonEmpty) array.updated(0, array.last).init else array**_ ?

Comment: @TimofeyGusev: yes, this would be better!

Answer (score 0):

The probles is with the array.lastOption. The result of this call returns an Option[PQOBject] and the Scala compiler detects that your array is not built by elements of the same type, and for that reason, the compiler returns Product with Serializable. If you uses last instead lastOption it compiles:

```
object testN1 {
  case class QueueObject[K, V](priority: K, e: V)(implicit prior: K => Ordered[K]) {
    require(e != null, "Can't put null element in queue. Please put another type of data!")
    type PQObject = QueueObject[K, V]

    def eq(other: PQObject): Int = if (priority >= other.priority) 1 else -1
  }

  case class QueueClass[K, V](container: Array[QueueObject[K, V]]) {
    type PQObject = QueueObject[K, V]
    type PQContainer = Array[PQObject]
    val array: PQContainer = container

    def deleteElement(array: PQContainer):PQContainer = array.updated(0, array.last).init
  }


}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot!)